# How to show Contact Alphabet list horizontally?

Tags: android, contacts

I'm trying to implement a Contact list and its alphabet bar.
I have searched a lot but whatever example i have got, all are showing the alphabet list vertically, but i need alphabet list horizontally above the contact grid view.

I have got some examples using listview, but i need on touch scroll, so I don't think listview is a good idea.

EDIT: Please check out the [link](http://www.brightec.co.uk/blog/android-listview-alphabet-scroller). what i am able to do is like this link

A

B

C

But i need A B C .. so on.

Any link or example is greatly appreciable

Thanks

Comment: so what exactly you needed ?

Answer (score 0):

### Edit 1

just change the whole layout to this,

and I would like to say just play with code you can do with your self

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".9"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sideIndex"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible, a ListView is only vertical.
You cannot make it's horizontal.
However, you can implement a horizontal scroll view as a horizontal ListView.
But it's hardly to control the scrolling of horizontal scroll view because it don't have setOnScrollListener.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Click here before scroll listview"
                android:onClick="Action"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My button 1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My button 2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My button 3" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My button 4" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My button 5" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My button 6" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My button 7" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My button 8" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My button 9" />
        </LinearLayout> 
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```